# Can't pass item argument in map to onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass `item` to `onClick` handler but it turns out that `item` is an object but it's just a string.

Here's my code:

```
const UploadMain = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="part">
        <h2 className="part-h2">category: </h2>
        <Options
          items={["one", "two", "three", "four"]}
          name={useSelector(state => state.upload.category)}
        />
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

const Options = props => {
  let [status, setStatus] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="options-container">
      <div className="options-header" onClick={() => setStatus(!status)}>
        <p>{props.name}</p>
      </div>
      <ul className={status ? "options-ul shown-ul" : "options-ul hidden-ul"}>
        {props.items.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <li
              key={index}
              value={item}
              onClick={item => {
                console.log(item) //this line logs some object
              }}
            >
              {item}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Object logged:
[image]

Comment: That object is logging event object, to pass the value of item you should use state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not a `item` but it is an `event` object. That ***item*** does not refer to ***item of items*** but it behaves like an alias to the event object.

instead change to this and put the log as is:

```
onClick={e => {
```

Comment: you beat me in speed :p

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code.

```js
{props.items.map((item, index) => {
    return (
        <li
            key={index}
            value={item}
            onClick={e => {
                console.log(item) //this line logs some object
            }}
        >
            {item}
        </li>
    );
})}
```

All you need to do is to change the item to e(event object differenct from item)

Answer (score 0):

Pass like this  `onClick={()=> handleClick(item)}` and define function

```
const handleClick = item =>{
    console.log(item);
   }
```

Improved Code

```
const Options = props => {
  const handleClick = item =>{
    console.log(item);
   }
  let [status, setStatus] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="options-container">
      <div className="options-header" onClick={() => setStatus(!status)}>
        <p>{props.name}</p>
      </div>
      <ul className={status ? "options-ul shown-ul" : "options-ul hidden-ul"}>
        {props.items.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <li
              key={index}
              value={item}
              onClick={()=> handleClick(item)}
            >
              {item}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Won't work, as you still redeclare `item`, that was already declared in the upper scope. Item becomes the Event when you do that here.

Answer (score 0):

```
    {props.items.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <li
          key={index}
          value={item}
          onClick={item => {
            console.log(item) //this line logs some object
          }}
        >
          {item}
        </li>
      );
    })}
```

If you take a closer look there, you first declare the item variable in the upper scope (declared in the `map` method), and then you declare another `item` variable in the lower scope, in the `onClick` handler.

To fix your issue - don't use the same variable name in the scope twice, it's bug and error prone. A linter would catch that, setup one if you don't have one already.

The variable in the onClick handler with always be the Event.
If you want to send the item variable to the onClick use:

```
   <li
    onClick={(ev) => console.log(item)}
   >
    {item}   
   </li>
```

Here I don't redeclare `item`, so it works as you want it.

Don't worry about the fact that this isn't perfectly optimised for now - you could use the `useCallback` hook to prevent that function from being created on every render, but it should not matter in small examples.